# Selenium Java: Unable to locate any element from child window

Tags: java, selenium

did anyone encounter the scenario like this

1. Executing within the parent window & iframe
2. After that click on a transaction and child window is popup(everything inside the child window is under a frame)

In this scenario, after switch to the child window, i can only perform driver.close().
Cant even get the title,the url,switch defaultContent,switch frame and etc...

Anyone got any idea or experience in this scenario? there is nothing can do in the child window except to close the child window.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the documentation?

- [Working with iFrames and frames](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browser/frames/)
- [Working with windows and tabs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browser/windows/)

Comment: yup, I did. This scenario is very weird, it just like selenium couldn't find the "door" to access the child window html body